# Do VS Database projects and Entity Framework work together?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, build, visual-studio-2012, database-project

I've always been intrigued by Visual Studio Database Projects, and while they seem to be quite capable, I've never used them to any great degree outside of simplistic proof-of-concept work. I want to try this for a new project, and I'm also interested in using an EF layer on top of it, but in past test projects this has involved some decent effort.

I'm curious: has Visual Studio matured its product integration to support a single workflow that builds the database project, builds the EF layer on top of it, and finally builds the code, without intermediate steps involved?

We are a small team and we don't have dedicated SQL developers, and our primary goal is to bring the database into Visual Studio and to get it nicely under source control (TFS), and to achieve strong integration between from end to end. We're interested in growing into EF, and will probably start simple by treating it like a simple ORM tool to begin with if possible.

Has anyone actually done this that can provide insight into the process?

Comment: Why would you want to "build your model from the database"? The main benefit of Entity Framework is that your conceptual model can differ from the physical model in the database. Otherwise, you're just using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I would build your database using the database tools of VS and then in your application, create an edmx that is points to your database.  When you change/update the database project, then just update your edmx and you are good to go.

Comment: @John Saunders: I had wished to ask specifically whether changes to the IDE in Visual Studio 2012 have facilitated this type of interaction. Removal of my tag feels strictly destructive for the sake of a silly rule.

Comment: If you simply import all database tables into the model, you will of course start off with a model that matches the database pretty closely. There's still no "workflow" for this case. You'd have to create your database project and import the database, then create your EF model from the same database.

Comment: @bwerks: I know it has been a while since you asked this question, but I wonder if you would mind sharing what you decided to do and how your experience has been.  Right now, the company I work for is using EF6 Code First, and letting EF generate scripts to modify our schema from model changes.  Other DB objects (procs, views, etc) have been placed under source control, but I'd like to use a Visual Studio DB project because it can do a compilation-like verification process between schema and stored procedures, views, etc.  Have you found EF Code-First and DB projects to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: How would you seed data an do database migration with a EDMX only model?

And how would you deploy the DB from automated scripts?

I have done this before with DB project and it works well, but wonder who well it would work to publish from EDMX model if need to make db changes

Answer (score 2):

We have used VS2014, tool seem much the same and early version
Don't think has been much changes over the years

We have EDMX model and a DB project in the solution
Does mean that you need to keep the db project up to date.
But this is easy to do, you just publish you EDMX to local box/target
Then can import the changes with a schema compare of local to the project.

So they you can still have Model driven DB design
And use the DB project to deploy changes to the Dev/Stage/Live boxes
And can publish with automated deployments also.

The db project has a post build scripts option
Where you can use it to do seed data
And also a pre-build where you can do db manipulation if need to change structure and types of fields types when the data is on a live db.

Schema compare tool are rather good in Visual Studio
Can compare a DB to DB, DB to Project, or Schema file to either also